# SQL to Array formation

Tags: arrays, format

This is what I am having trouble with.

I have this query: `$sql_words = "SELECT word_title FROM words";`

which contains hundreds of words and need to output the results like this
meaning putting the results in an array like.

```
$varriable = array('word1','word2');
```

could you give a help?

Comment: You need to specify which language you are using

Comment: Sorry, 
Its Php and mysql